# Can I change the firebug console background color?

Tags: firebug

I'd prefer the firebug window to have a dark background color and light text (or even just a gray background instead of white would be enough).

Is there way I can do this, either through adjusting firebug's original files or perhaps through using an extension?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a nice dark theme for firebug (only work on firefox)

http://userstyles.org/styles/85647/firebug-nightliontheme

Answer (score 5):

There's no option for changing the colors but there are some [themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/themes/) like [NASA Night Launch](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/nasa-night-launch/) changing the colors.
You also have the possibility to change the colors by yourself. To do so you can either open the XPI file and change the styles there or fetch the source from github, change it there and build your own XPI.

To change your XPI:

1. Click Firefox Menu > *Help* > *Troubleshooting Information*
2. Click the *Show Folder* button
3. Open the `extensions` folder
4. Open the file named `firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi` with a packer program that is able to open ZIP files (an XPI file is just a renamed ZIP)
5. In there go to `skin` > `classic`
6. Change the CSS files in there as you like (the main panel colors are defined in `panelbase.css` inside the `.panelNode` rule)

To fetch the source:

1. Fetch the Firebug source from [github](https://github.com/firebug/firebug) repository
2. In there go to `skin` > `classic`
3. Change the CSS files in there as you like (the main panel colors are defined in `panelbase.css` inside the `.panelNode` rule)
4. [Build the XPI file](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Simple_Firebug_build) using [Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) (integrated in many IDEs)
5. Drag & drop that XPI file into your Firefox to install it

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the latest FireFox version and it seems that you have a Theme option built-in the debug console. Just hit the gear icon at the top and then select the theme you want: Dark light theme. Voilà!