# Disable word-wrap in firebug

Tags: firebug

When I unfold too many nodes, and the node position is too close to the right sidebar, so it has not enough room, instead of the scrollbar to get smaller (so I can scroll to the right to see the whole line), firebug breaks the line. How can I disable this behaviour? On chrome I have the option to disable line breaking (word-wrap).

Note: I'm not sure if this question is for Stackoverflow, so I suppose it can be moved to the appropriate site by a moderator.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have better asked inside the [Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug). That's normally the only place were the Firebug developers (like me) are answering questions.

Unfortunately there's currently no such option within Firebug.
You can either

1. [add an enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry?template=User%20enhancement%20request) to add an option for toggling the display, or
2. change it by yourself. Firebug is [open source](https://github.com/firebug/firebug) and formatting is based on CSS, so feel free to dive into its code. In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972885/can-i-change-the-firebug-console-background-color/11188561#11188561) I shortly explained how to do that.